# Keyerror Display on pyatogui in kivy android app

Tags: python, kivy, pyautogui

i imported my kivy app to android, but on run it crashes and gives me the above error. I tried moving the location of display 0 but it did not change the error. it tells me the error happens when importing pyautogui.

Code:

```
import time

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
import pyautogui
import os


class layy(App):

    os.environ['DISPLAY'] = ':0'
    global t
    t = TextInput(hint_text='insert text')

    global c
    global s
    s = TextInput(hint_text='insert time till begin')
    c = TextInput(hint_text='insert amount')

    def bot(self, instance):

        am = c.text
        if (am == ""):
            am = '0'
        l = int(am)

        apm = t.text
        m = str(apm)
        if (m == ""):
            m = 'hi'

        pm = c.text
        if (pm == ""):
            pm = '0'
        o = int(pm)
        base = 0

        time.sleep(o)
        while (base < l):
           pyautogui.typewrite(m)
           pyautogui.press('enter')
           base = base + 1

    def build(self):



        b = Button(text='Start Spam')
        b.bind(on_press=self.bot)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        sublay1 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay2 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        sublay3 = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')

        layout.add_widget(sublay1)
        sublay1.add_widget(t)

        layout.add_widget(sublay2)
        sublay2.add_widget(s)
        sublay2.add_widget(c)

        layout.add_widget(sublay3)
        sublay3.add_widget(b)

        return layout

if __name__ == '__main__':
    layy().run()
```

If anyone knows what to do, please tell me. Sorry if it is simple, i'm new to python.

Comment: So what is the error? Although regardless, it probably just doesn't support android. The DISPLAY env var is related to X11, which Android doesn't use.

Comment: If you just want to interact with the Kivy app you also don't need pyautogui, you can write python code to make Kivy do whatever you want.

Comment: If so, I can't find anything on that. Can you please give an example of kivy controlling the keyboard?

Comment: Do you actually want to inject key events, or just have the gui display text automatically? What result do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to use it to rapidly send messages in an external app, so I use the time.sleep to delay it until I open the app and it starts sending messages.

Comment: So you want to use pyautogui to control an app that is _not_ the kivy app?

Comment: Yes, I control the keyboard while in another app to send messages on said app

Comment: I'm afraid this is probably impossible on Android, and pyautogui definitely won't know how to do it. Android supports some ui automation stuff, but you'd need to read how to use the java api, and I'd guess it's only available for debugging use. Perhaps that would be suitable for you, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: If I can grant root access to the app I can probably do it, is there a way to do that?

Comment: You can root an android device, but it won't solve the problem that pyautogui has no idea how to do its thing on android.